# Is it theoretically possible to prevent or deter a star from becoming a black hole?

Tags: black-holes

Suppose NASA decides too many black holes are being produced in a year, so it decides to do something about that. Given our current scientific knowledge, is there theoretically any way NASA could accomplish this non-trivial feat?

Comment: Not with it's current state of funding, no.

Comment: I'm afraid this is a bit like asking if we can beat the second law of thermodynamics. Yes, we can, locally, but usually it comes at the price of making things worse on a global scale. To prevent formation of black holes, you'd have to fuel stars somehow so that they can keep opposing the gravitational pressure. Or you have to strip them off of material to ease off the gravitational pressure. We are far from accomplishing feats of that magnitude.

Comment: Decrease mass adequately or increase energy adequately.

Comment: ...Use a black hole to absorb the material thereby preventing the formation of a black hole. Its stupid but it answers the question.

Comment: I'm not sure why that would be a benefit.   For a star to go black (and once stars go black, they never go back), er, sorry.   But a healthy share of the outer material gets blown off and you get all kinds of fun things like heavy elements.    What's more valuable, the outer layers of H, He, O, Si, etc or the more exotic elements that fly away from the star when it goes kaboom?   I think the exotic elements are more interesting than the matter in a star that's big enough to go nova.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as it's not a black hole yet, you can always pull mass out of the star until it's too light to collapse into a singularity. Physically accomplishing that is far outside the range of current energy capacities, but there's nothing particularly hard about it from a physics standpoint. Just slam a high speed object into the star's edge and the momentum will knock some nuclear soup past escape velocity. Repeat for a few billion years. Problem solved.